# Solving abs equations with complex solution

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I want to solve equations containing absolute values for complex solutions. Eg: $$|x+2| - 7 = 0$$ has real solution as $\{-9, 5\}$ and complex solution as $\{-2 + 7\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}θ}\}$. Real solutions can be easily derived but how do I get complex solutions?

Also can I get some references where there is an explanation for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

$$|x+2|-7=0$$ means

$$|x-(-2)|=7$$

It is a circle centered at $(-2,0)$ with radius $7$.

$$x=-2+7\exp(i \theta), \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$$

Comment: Can you provide me with some references, I cannot find it anywhere. Would be a great help.

Comment: Section [2.9](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~dwm/Courses/1CA_1995/1CA-NALL.pdf)